# how to access image picture in a TImageCollection in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi

I've loaded several images in a TImageCollection. I want to access the pictures inside to copy to a fastreport and alike.
I've tried something like this:

```
var
  vi_imagen :TImageCollectionSourceItem;
  bmp: tbitmap;
  MyPicture: TfrxPictureView;
begin
    vi_imagen := imagecollection.images[1].sourceimages[0];
    bmp.Assign(vi_imagen); 

    MyPicture.Picture.Assign(bmp); 
end;
```

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Yesterday Ctrl+Space didnt show vi_imagen properties and documentation didn't help much, so I was a bit lost. Today I can see the image property. The reason to use this component instead of TImageList is to use it as a repository for images of different sizes, what TImageList can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider [Uwe Raabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72014870/65863) and understand the the purpose of [`TImageCollection`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ImageCollection.TImageCollection). Maybe you simply need a [`TImageList`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TImageList) component instead.

`ImageCollection.GetBitmap()` first looks for an exact size match. If not found, it creates a scaled bitmap according to the requested size by picking the best source.

If you still need to access a specific source image by its index, it could be done like this:

```
// Assign to a TPicture instance
Image.Picture.Assign(ImageCollection.Images[X].SourceImages[Y].Image);
// Or assign to a TBitmap instance
Bitmap.Assign(ImageCollection.Images[X].SourceImages[Y].Image);
```

Normally, you should not use this approach, except in some very specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of `TImageCollection` is to provide images in different sizes. For that it offers methods to retrieve an image of a specific size. The simplest is `GetBitmap`, which takes the Index of the image and the requested size.

```
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := imagecollection.GetBitmap(1, 48, 48); // get 48 pixel 
  try
    MyPicture.Picture.Assign(bmp); 
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```